# Scala: are the initial values in an Array[Double] safe to use?

Tags: scala

When an Array[Double] containing all zeros is required, is it safe to use

```
    val allZeros = new Array[Double](10)
    val whatever = allZeros( 5 )     // guaranteed to be 0.0, not null?
    assert( whatever == 0.0 )        // succeeds
```

or should I stick to

```
    val allZeros = Array.fill[Double](10)( 0.0 )
```

I am aware that the first version works, but is this a guarantee the language makes, i.e. will it always be safe? Double could theoretically also be initialized with `null` (although, thinking about it, as a language designer I'd rather not make that kind of change :-).

Comment: Only `AnyRef`'s and subclasses can have `null` value. `Double` is `AnyVal`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double in Scala is not an object like `java.lang.Double`, but the primitive type `double`. Thus the default value is 0. You can use your first version, which is perfectly safe.

However, I tend to prefer the second version, because it introduce another level of safety: it is self documented.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's safe. This is actually a guarantee Java makes and it carries on to Scala.